# Show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

> Suppose that $X$ is a space with the property that
>   for any point $p \in X$ there is a  map
>   $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(1) = \{p\}$.
>   Show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Solution:

Suppose that $x \neq y$ are points in $X$. Choose
$f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 1$
and $f(y) \neq 1$ and open disjoint intervals
around $1$ and $f(y)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (which is possible
since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff).

Now we are done if we can say that the inverse
images of these intervals under $f$ are open
disjoint sets in $X$ containing $x$ and $y$, respectively.
Because then $X$ is Hausdorff.

---

$f$ is a map, i.e. a continuous function, and therefore its
inverse takes open sets to open sets.

This is probably a very simple question and bordering on stupid
for you experienced topologists
but i just wonder how we can be sure that the inverse takes
**disjoint** open sets to **disjoint** open sets?

Comment: On preimage of intersection: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228711/what-are-the-strategies-i-can-use-to-prove-f-1s-cap-t-f-1s-cap-f or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516374/how-to-prove-f-1b-1-cap-b-2-f-1b-1-cap-f-1b-2 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144870/verifying-a-proposition-on-image-and-preimage-fa-cap-b-subseteq-fa-cap-fb

Comment: The condition on $X$ can also be expressed by saying that [all singletons are zero sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180826/in-which-topological-spaces-is-every-singleton-set-a-zero-set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true for every map that the inverse image of disjoint sets are disjoint sets.

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be any map between sets,  $A, B\subseteq Y$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Suppose there is an element
$x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$. Then we have $f(x)\in A\cap B=\emptyset$ a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you! I wish it wasnt 13 years since i took my real analysis course :)